# How would I make my python coded guessing game replace a letter that has been correctly guessed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is that it will show some underscores to represent the word to be guessed, then the player is supposed to enter a letter they think is in the word. Then the code should return the underscores, this time replacing the correct underscore with its corresponding letter. The problem is it doesn't do the last step

```py
import random
import time
from typing import List

word = ['dog','cat','bird','chair']
a = list(random.choice(word))

for letter in a:
    e = print('_',end = '')
    time.sleep(.25)

big = str(e)
count = big.count('_')

while int(count) > int(0):
    def fun(self):
        e.replace(a.index(big),dog)
        for letter in a:
            print('_',end = '')
            time.sleep(.25)

dog = input('\ninput letter\n')
if dog in a:
    print(fun(dog))
else:
    for letter in a:
        print('_',end = '')
        time.sleep(.25)
```

Here is the entirety of the code I have if needed
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Many problems.**

1. `e` is `None` because `print()` returns `None`
2. `replace` replaces a character/substring for character/substring, it does not take index
3. `str` types are immutable so this type of thing is probably best done with a `list`

**Solution:**

```
import random
import time
from typing import List

word = ['dog','cat','bird','chair']
chosen = random.choice(word)
print(chosen)

def display(big):
    for letter in big:
        print(letter,end = '')
        time.sleep(.25)

def fun(char):
    i = chosen.index(char)
    big[i] = char
    display(big)

big = ["_" for letter in chosen]
count = big.count('_')
display(big)

while count > 0:
    char = input('\ninput letter\n')
    if char in chosen:
        fun(char)
        count -= 1
    else:
        display(big)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your code has too many problems

---

- You are assigning print function into a value, which returns `None`
- You are defining a function inside a while loop
- You can't pass integer/index as parameter in replace method
- After getting its first input, it just runs the last if-else statements and the code ends there
- `self` is not used inside the function

Your code should actually be like:

```py
import random

word = ['dog','cat','bird','chair']
a = list(random.choice(word))
b = ['_']*len(a)

print(''.join(b))
while b != a:
    inp = input('Input a letter: ')[0]
    for i,j in enumerate(a):
        if j==inp:
            b[i] = j
    print(''.join(b))

b = ''.join(b)
print('The answer is', b, '\nCongrats! You found it!')
```

Tell me if its not working...